# R knit function resulting in blank document

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, render

When ever I try the knit button on R, I'm getting a blank html document. This is what I get in the render output.

[image: Render Output]

There are no error besides the name, which it resolves itself.

This is the top part of the document

````
---
title: "STAT 488: Assignment 1"
author: "Submit to the Assignment 1 dropbox on BB by 11:00 pm, May 27 2022"

output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include = TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

I have tried downloading many different R packages, I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Sometimes code can get messed up when posting to Stack Overflow. In your actual document do you have spaces before the first `---`? Do you have a blank line between author and output?  That first block needs to be written in YAML format and it can be picky about whitespace.

Comment: The spaces before the --- was not there so I edited it.

The author and output was in the code

Comment: But the extra space after author is there?

Comment: Can you add the text of the error (instead of, or in addition to, the screenshot)?

Comment: That is the entire output of the render. There are no errors, I just receive a blank html

Comment: Could it be that in the render command you have `output_format = 'html_document'`and in the Rmd code `output: pdf_document`

Comment: Something is wrong with my RStudio, I made a new Rmd file, copy pasted my entire file, and it worked fine.